# How would you convert f32.reinterpret_i32 and f64.promote_f32 to javascript?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm trying to convert this small bit of Webassembly to JavaScript, but I don't know how the commands f32.reinterpret_i32 and f64.promote_f32 would be written. Here is what I am trying to convert:

```
local.get $var0
f32.reinterpret_i32
f64.promote_f32
```

I tried looking on Mozilla docs to understand the methods more, but to no avail. They didn't really give a clear explanation of how these worked. For example, the page on reinterpret said "The reinterpret instructions, are used to reinterpret the bits of a number as a different type." This definition doesn't give a clear and concise understanding of how it actually reinterprets the bits, it just says that it does. So I came here to ask for help on what these actually do and how I could write these in JavaScript. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `DataView`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
let view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));
view.setInt32(0, var0, true);
let result = view.getFloat32(0, true);
```

Comment: Btw, do you know if WebAssembly has defined endianness?

Comment: Yes, it's little endian.